# SQL Count & Join

Tags: sql, jupyter-notebook

Just not sure what I need to do here. I have to count the total movies based off a certain production company, so the question is this:

How many movies in the database were produced by Pixar Animation Studios?

This is my SQL code so far, I work off Jupyter:

```
select movies.movie_id, movies.title, productioncompanies.production_company_id, productioncompanies.production_company_name
from movies, productioncompanies
where production_company_name = "Pixar Animation Studios"
```

Comment: you can use the `count` function if you are looking to get the amount of movies.

Comment: here is a link provided with some examples: [Link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp) , Can you specify what exactly the problem you are facing

Comment: You can use the count function as Mohamed said and you have to join the two tables.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is the following:

```
select count(*)
  from movies join productioncompanies
    on movies.production_company_id = productioncompanies.production_company_id
 where production_company_name = 'Pixar Animation Studios';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
%%sql 
select count(*), p.production_company_name
from productioncompanymap as m
left join productioncompanies as p
on m.production_company_id = p.production_company_id
where production_company_name = 'Pixar Animation Studios'
```

Comment: Code dumps do not make for good answers. You should explain how and why this solves their problem. I recommend reading, [How do I write a good answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for the vague detail to my question. I am still new to stack overflow so still finding my feet.

I have to link two databases of movies. The first database has a set of movie details (movie name, budget, rating, release date and reviews as well as a movie_id), the second table has a genre_id and genre's listing. I need to link the movie to the production comapny i.e. Monsters inc. to Pixar Animations, but the two databases does not have a primary key to link each other to. When I have the list of movies linked to the production company, I have to count the total movies per production company.

I hope this gives more detail, oh yeah, I am a student and this is one of my tests I have to do. I am unsure of how to join the tables and where.